# Is it possible to apply fixes on Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Update 3

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015u3 is serviced by cumulative updates with KB3165756, which contains, among other things, fixes to the C++ compiler and libraries.

However KB3165756 refuses to do anything on a computer where Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Update 3 is installed. It really wants one of VS Pro, Enterprise, Community or Express.

Are there special patches for Visual C++ Build Tools, or is it not updated at all and so it is actually a better idea to switch to Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop, in order to be able to receive patches?

Comment: You might ask over at msdn's VS forums for product specific info.

Comment: And if you get an answer come back here and let us know!

Comment: I just asked on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c986110f-5bf2-4042-878b-5e2b197003ab/is-it-possible-to-apply-fixes-on-visual-c-build-tools-2015-update-3?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I got on MSDN Visual Studio Development > Visual Studio Setup and Installation forum:

> > However KB3165756 refuses to do anything on a computer where Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Update 3 is installed. It really wants one of VS Pro, Enterprise, Community or Express.

It is reasonable, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx and it describes this update is applies to

- Visual Studio Professional 2015
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
- Visual Studio Community 2015
- Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web
- Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop
- Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows 10

I have researched around and it looks like there is no special update for the Visual C++ Build Tools 2015, and refer to this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/

The latest release of the Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 is here: Download Visual C++ Build Tools 2015

If you still want to install, it looks like you need a VS 2015 RTM update version on your computer. Since the VS community 2015 with update 2 and Visual Studio Express version are free and you can think about it.

Best regards,

Sara